# prove that the inverse of an isomorphisim between two covering maps is an isomorphisim without assuming connectness

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I am reading hatcher's algebraic topology. And the following is the definition of covering map in his book:

> (**The definition of evenly covered**) Giving a space $\widetilde{X}$ and a map $p: \widetilde{X} \rightarrow X$. An open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$, or just an open set $U$ in $X$ is called **evenly covered**, if the following statement satisfied:
> $p^{-1}(U)$ is a union of disjoint open sets $\cup_{\alpha}{V_{\alpha}}$ , such that each of which is mapped homeomorphically onto $U$ by $p$. To be concrete, $p|V_{\alpha}: V_{\alpha} \rightarrow U$ is a homeomorphisim.

> (**The definition of covering space and covering map**) Given a space $X$,  a **covering space** of $X$ consists of a space $\widetilde{X}$ and a map $p: \widetilde{X} \rightarrow X$ such that each point $x \in X$ is **evenly covered** by $p$. To be concrete, for each point $x \in X$ there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$ such that $p^{-1}(U)$ is a union of disjoint open sets each of which is mapped homeomorphisically onto $U$ by $p$. To be more concrete, there is disjoint open sets $\{V_\alpha\}$ in $\widetilde{X}$  such that $p^{-1}(U) = \cup_{\alpha}V_\alpha$ and $p|V_{\alpha}: V_{\alpha} \rightarrow U$ is a homeomorphisim.

And then he defines **an isomorphism between covering spaces**:

> An isomorphism between covering space $p_1: \widetilde{X}_1 \rightarrow X$ and  $p_2: \widetilde{X}_2 \rightarrow X$ is a homeomorphism $f: \widetilde{X}_1 \rightarrow \widetilde{X}_2$ such that $p_1 = p_2 \circ f$.

and states that:

> The inverse $f^{−1}$ is then also an isomorphism, and the composition of two isomorphisms is an isomorphism, so we have an equivalence relation.
> Here are my questions:

(**Question 1**) The problem I have when checking $f^{−1}$ is then also an isomorphism is that I have to assume $X$ is at least locally connected. With $X$ being locally connected I can prove that $p_1 = p_2 \circ f^{-1}$. But I cannot prove it without any assuming about $X$. How to prove it wihout any assuming about the space $X$?

(**Question 2**) Or is that when we discussing a covering map $p: \widetilde{X} \rightarrow X$, we always on assumes some prerequisites on the space $\widetilde{X}$ or $X$? Hatcher adds these prerequisites adhoclly on dicussing about variant topics about covering space. And he does discuss cases for $\widetilde{X}$ no being connected (for example on the section about "[Representing Covering Spaces by Permutations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798164/representing-covering-spaces-by-permutations)"). Is that we should assume for a covering map $p: \widetilde{X} \rightarrow X$, $\widetilde{X}$(or $X$) is locally path connected?

Thanks!

Comment: For $f^{-1}$ to be an isomorphism you want $p_2=p_1\circ f^{-1}$, not $p_1=p_2\circ f^{-1}$.  This follows immediately by composing both sides of $p_1=p_2\circ f$ with $f^{-1}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yeah you are right! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just category theory: we know that $$p_1 = p_2 \circ f$$

but then we can apply $f^{-1}$ on the right to both sides and get

$$p_1 \circ f^{-1} =  (p_2 \circ f) \circ f^{-1} = p_2 \circ (f \circ f^{-1}) = p_2$$ which states that $f^{-1}$ is *also* an isomorphism between covering spaces (the other way).

Composition goes the same way. The structure of the spaces itself is irrelevant. It's a property of diagrams.